# Отправка запроса на удаление на REST сервер

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, rest, spring-boot

Клиент шлет запрос на REST сервер на удаление записи.
Исполнение на Angular

```
    $scope.deleteItem = function(id) {
            var url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/message/' + id;
            var config = { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}};

            $http.delete(url, config).then(function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }, function(response){
                console.log(response);
            });
```

На стороне сервера Spring boot

```
    @RequestMapping(
            value = "api/message/{id}",
            method = RequestMethod.DELETE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteMessage(@PathVariable Long id) {
        if (!messageService.delete(id)) {
            throw  new DataNotFoundException("Data with id=" + id + " not found.");
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Successfully deleted user");
    }
```

Возвращает текст, это заглушка, на самом деле я пока не знаю, что правильно возвращать в таком случае, по идеи true, хотя Angular может ответ проверить и со строкой == "готово". В общем если дадите доп. совет то спасибо.

Сейчас получаю ответ на стороне сервера:

> Resolved exception caused by Handler execution:
>   org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content
>   type 'null' not supported

лог в консоль браузера:

```
DELETE http://localhost:8080/api/message/1 415 
config: Object 
data: Object  
headers: (d)  
status: 415  
statusText: ""
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Возможно у вас вот сюда `"api/message/{id}"` приходит этот самый null? Удаление из базы происходит?

Comment: @GenCloud Я честно говоря не понимаю в чем там ошибка, на выходе переменная url имеет вид http://localhost:8080/api/message/1 (или другой id).

Comment: @Виктор Удаление не происходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мое решение:
серверная сторона

```
//Delete the item
@RequestMapping(
        value = "api/message/{id}",
        method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteMessage(@PathVariable Long id) {
    if (!messageService.delete(id)) {
        throw  new DataNotFoundException("Data with id=" + id + " not found.");
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

клиентская сторона

```
$scope.deleteItem = function (id) {

    $http.delete($scope.url + 'message/' + id).success(function (response) {
        делаем что то, например удаляем из массива или перезагружаем страницу
    }, function (response) {
        console.log("Return error");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) запрос на маппер так никогда не пишется 
2) ссылка на конкретный реквест контроллер должна иметь вид - /api/message/ + id
3) взгляните на мой пример регистрации пользователя, должен вам помочь с вашим примером

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/account",
        data: JSON.stringify(reg),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.gritter.add({
                title: '<i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Поздавляем',
                text: 'Вы успешно зарегистрированы!',
                sticky: true,
                time: '',
                class_name: 'gritter-info'
            });
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location = "/login.jsp";
            }, 2000);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status) {
            $('.login-wrapper').removeClass('fadeOutUp');
            var data = jqXHR.responseJSON;

            $.gritter.add({
                title: '<i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Ой, произошла ошибка!',
                text: data.msg,
                sticky: false,
                time: '',
                class_name: 'gritter-danger'
            });
        }
    });
```